# How to represent a TextFile as an Array

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a text file full of stopwords. I would like to represent this file as an array. I dont want to convert the file into an array on the fly - I want create code (code generation) or represent the text file as

```
var stopwordsarr = new string[] {"stopword1", "stopword2", "stopword3", "etc.."};
```

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate code, whip up a small Console app like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  var fname = args[0];
  var words = File.ReadAllLines(fname);

  Console.WriteLine("var stopWords = new string[] {");
  for(int i = 0; i < words.Length; ++i) {
    string word = words[i];
    Console.Write("@\"{0}\"", word.Replace("\"", "\\\""));
    if(i < words.Length - 1) {
      Console.Write(",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.WriteLine("};");
}
```

Then you can just to: `makestopwords.exe somefile.txt > stopwords.cs` and voila

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file has the words listed on separate lines:

```
var stopWordsArr = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want [File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) ?